# return false not working in jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a registration form with jquery ajax. My jQuery Code is as follow :

```
function validateData()
{
    var email = jQuery("#email").val();
    var username = jQuery("#username").val();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;   
    var regex = new RegExp(/^\+?[0-9(),.-]+$/); 
    if(!emailReg.test(email))   
    {
        alert('Please enter valid email');
        return false;   
    }
    var agreement = jQuery("#agereement").is(":checked");
    if(agreement == false)
    {
        alert("Please agree with the agreement !!! ");
        return false;
    }
    var pass = jQuery("#password").val();
    var repass = jQuery("#repeatpass").val();
    if(pass != repass)
    {
        alert("Password & Repeat Password Should be same");
        return false;
    }

        var FirstData = "email=" + email+"&username="+username;
        var url = "ajaxcheck.php";
        jQuery.ajax({
            dataType : 'html',
            type: 'GET',
            url : url,
            data : FirstData,
            complete : function() { },
            success: function(data) 
                {
                    if(data == '')
                    {
                        alert("No Problem");
                        var flag = "true";
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Username Or Email ID Already Exists");
                        var flag = "false";                     
                    }

                }   
        });
        alert(flag);
        return flag;
}
</script>
```

When I submit the form and enters the value of username which is already exists in DB then it alerts the `Username Or Email ID Already Exists` but submit the form instead of staying on the page. What Should I do if it error comes then it should stay on the page instead of submitting the form

Comment: You know what `asynchronous` means, right?

Comment: @u_mulder, OP is using `async:false,` meaning the ajax call will/should be synchronous

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks, then move on to string values)

Comment: I would recommend doing more validation using html5 instead of javascript, use required, and correct input types instead

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```js
    var flag = "true";
…
    var flag = "false";
…
return flag;
```

The problem is that `"true"` and `"false"` are [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) containing the word “true” or “false”. To get the actual [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) values `true` or `false`, get rid of the quotes:

```js
    var flag = true;
…
    var flag = false;
…
return flag;
```

Event handlers only understand boolean return values, not strings.

Comment: I have done this but it does not alert the value of flag also

Comment: I wasn’t saying you have to remove the `alert`s in your existing code – you only need to change the two lines with `var flag =`. If you keep your existing `alert`s, they should still work after this change.

Comment: In console it is saying flag is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Use `onsubmit` in form tag

```
<form onsubmit="return validateData();">
 ....
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Also apply as @Rory suggest, replace `"true"` to `true` and `"false"` to `false`

Comment: Also what you get first , `alert flag value` or `user already exist` ?

Comment: I think you should use `async:false,`

Comment: can you also share your html form tag ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to help you from another angle.

Here is an example on how to do form validation (with bootstrap/php/jquery): http://formvalidation.io/examples/contact-form/

Ajax ".done" happens when you get a successful response from the server and ".fail" happens when sending a request or receiving the response has failed. Assuming you want to check if email exists then you can use something in the lines of:

```
if(response.IsEmailValid === 'false')
{
    $('#alertContainer')
        .removeClass('alert-success')
        .addClass('alert-warning')
        .html('Sorry, email has been taken')
        .show()
}
```

Comment: As far as I know in Javascript "0" == '0' ==0 and "true" == 'true' ==true.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `flag` to strings, not boolean values. Try using `true` and `false` instead of `"true"` and `"false"`, both of which are truthy.